# On my Flutter I have a list of data and I want to send this data to another screen but there is an error that I don't understand how to solve it

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use navigator to pass data but i can't solve the error
I actually don't know how to pass data between screens properly using the navigator in cases like this I've learned but I still don't understand how because every tutorial I watch and other ways from the internet each have a different way

This is the image

[List of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqJVI.png)

[Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTzPu.png)

[2nd Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhhUQ.png)

[class for list of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QAmR.png)

here's the error:

[image: here's the error]

below is the full code list of data and navigator

````
import 'package:semester3_prjct/test.dart';
import 'data.dart';
import 'package:semester3_prjct/slide.dart';
import 'package:semester3_prjct/navBar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ProJect',
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Color(0xFF9FA8DA)),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final List<Isi> isi = [
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 1',
        gbr: 'images/gbr1.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.6000/porsi'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 2',
        gbr: 'images/gbr2.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.6000/kotak'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 3',
        gbr: 'images/gbr3.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.7000/porsi'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 4',
        gbr: 'images/gbr4.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.8000/porsi'),
    Isi(text: 'Makanan 5', gbr: 'images/gbr5.jpg', harga: 'Harga: Rp.5000/ptg'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 6',
        gbr: 'images/gbr6.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.7000/kotak'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 7',
        gbr: 'images/gbr7.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.8000/porsi'),
    Isi(
        text: 'Makanan 8',
        gbr: 'images/gbr8.jpg',
        harga: 'Harga: Rp.12000/porsi'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: Navbar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[200],
        elevation: 0.0,
        flexibleSpace: Slideku(),
        toolbarHeight: 137,
        leading: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 10,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.indigo[200],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      ))),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              childAspectRatio: (4 / 4.8),
              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
              children: isi
                  .map((item) => Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: Colors.indigo,
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo.shade200, width: 2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Test(isi: isi)));
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.asset(item.gbr,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, height: 125),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    item.text,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700]),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 4,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    item.harga,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 11, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )))))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: please share  your code as well to get better answer.

Comment: could you show the error showing in console?

Comment: please use text for your code instead of images.

Comment: btw, you're giving a `List<Isi> isi` instead of `Isi isi` for your `Test` widget. Hence the error

Comment: Don't upload images. Share your code for others to understand

Comment: Please add your other code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following code:

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Test(isi: isi)));
  },
```

you're giving variable `isi` which is a list:

```
 final List<Isi> isi
```

But your `Test` widget need an `Isi` object:

```
class Test extends StatelesWidget {
    final Isi isi;

    ....

}
```

To solve the problem, use the `item` from your map:

```
isi.map((item) => Card( ...
```

So, your code should be something like this:

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Test(isi: item)));
  },
```